# Kali linux on xenserver 6.5 is not displaying in VM console

Tags: linux, debian, xenserver

I have a problem with installed Kali Linux 2016 x64 as VM on Xenserver 6.5.
Installing done successful, but when system starting, it not displaying in VM console.
I know, what system started, because ping on it working. But I can't do anything with it. Last message in console is "`Boot device: Hard disk - success.`"
I can't connect to Kali Linux even via ssh, it not automatically starting.
What can I do with this problem? Any ideas?

Comment: try to restart the toolstack. it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If it's the Kali Linux livecd/usb system, it should log you in as root by default if I recall right. Try typing `ALT+F2` to get gnome's `Enter a command:` prompt, then type `service sshd start`. I think the default root password is `toor`. Then you can at least get in and try to find out what's wrong.

If that doesn't work, try pressing enter a few times and waiting a few minutes after it boots up. You might have to get by a prompt asking you if you want to boot into the live environment or do an install.